# javascript excution function execution

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to hide a div using JavaScript in this function

```
function changepersonal() {
document.getElementById("personal1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("personal2").style.display = "inline";
}
```

it executed correctly, but for seconds and back to the previous status.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get help from the ones among us who don't happen to master divination

Comment: Add your html or create demo.